# Trying to install Java to use for scala, java: command not found

Tags: java, scala, path, installation

when i type

```
find / -name java
```

i get

```
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers.d/java
/etc/bash_completion.d/java
/home/natecraft/.npm/JSV/4.0.2/package/jsdoc-toolkit/java
/home/natecraft/Documents/dithat/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.0/java
/home/natecraft/Documents/tributary/static/java
/home/natecraft/Documents/tributary/node_modules/jsonlint/node_modules/JSV/jsdoc-   toolkit/java
/home/natecraft/Downloads/usr/java
/home/natecraft/.local/share/Trash/files/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.8.0/java
/usr/lib/ure/share/java
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/java
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ref-1.0.5/ext/java
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coderay-1.0.9/lib/coderay/scanners/java
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/java
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/java
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coderay-1.1.0/lib/coderay/scanners/java
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json_pure-1.8.0/java
/usr/share/java
```

Do I have it installed and just need to add it to a path or something or do I need to install it altogether?
Please answer this like you're talking to a total noob.  Thanks!

Comment: More of a question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Only somewhat related, but for future reference, `which java` or `type java` is better for this kind of check.

Comment: @waffleparadox: Need a few exclamation points after that one... Also, (once the locate DB has been updated, either via cron or manualy) `locate */java*` can be helpful.